# Feedme API call with auth token

Tags: plugin-feedme, craft4

I want to use the feedme plugin to get data from an API that uses API Tokens as authentication. Of course without adding the API Key, I get the following error in Feedme `response: {"error":{"type":"Unauthorized"}}`. Where can I add the API key so that I can fetch the data? I checked all the options inside the plugin and there's nothing about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to send the API key via the headers.

You'll need to add a feedme config file where you can add request options.
see https://docs.craftcms.com/feed-me/v4/get-started/configuration.html#example-requestoptions

For example:

````
return [
    '*' => [
        'requestOptions' => [
            'headers' => [
                'X-API-KEY' => 'xxxxxxxx',
            ],
        ],
    ]
];```
````